# how maintain a session with javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm creating an application with javascript, but all the HTML content is created via Ajax, and it's all okay, but I had a doubt when the user for any reason presses F5 and reloads all the content. To maintain the actual session I made cookies for the structure and for all information this will reload via Ajax, for security reasons I don't caching with cookies, this is my way to maintain the session, but I have a question, is there another way to maintain an state of an ajax session? Or I will still doing this.

Comment: If you can't cache it for security reasons, you _have_ to reload it..

Comment: That's why you have to take a look at AngularJS https://angularjs.org/ and this blog post http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs